# Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space with dual space $V^∗.$ Then every ordered basis for $V^∗$ is the dual basis for some basis for $V.$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space with dual space $V^∗.$
Then every ordered basis for $V^∗$ is the dual basis for some basis for $V.$

The proof of this result uses the two theorems below:

> Theorem 2.24. Suppose that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with the ordered basis $β = \{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}.$ Let $f_i (1 ≤ i ≤ n)$ be the ith coordinate function with respect to $β$ as just defined, and let $β^∗ = \{f_1, f_2,..., f_n\}.$ Then $β^∗$ is an ordered basis for $V^∗,$ and, for any $f ∈ V^∗,$ we have
> $f = n\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)f_i.$

> Theorem 2.26. (For a vector $x ∈ V,$ we define $\hat x: V^∗ → F$ by $x(f) = f(x)$ for every $f ∈ V^∗.$) Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and define $ψ: V → V^{∗∗}$ by $ψ(x) = \hat x.$ Then $ψ$ is an isomorphism.

The proof given is as follows:

> Proof. Let $\{f_1, f_2,..., f_n\}$ be an ordered basis for $V^∗.$ We may combine Theorems 2.24 and 2.26 to conclude that for this basis for $V^∗$ there exists a dual basis $\{\hat x_1, \hat x_2,...,\hat x_n\}$ in $V^{∗∗},$ that is, $δ_{ij} = \hat x_i(f_j ) = f_j (x_i)$ for all $i$ and $j.$ Thus $\{f_1, f_2,..., f_n\}$ is the dual basis of $\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}.$

---

However, I don't understand the meaning of the line, "We may combine Theorems 2.24 and 2.26 to conclude that for this basis for $V^∗$ there exists a dual basis $\{\hat x_1, \hat x_2,...,\hat x_n\}$ in $V^{∗∗},$ that is, $δ_{ij} = \hat x_i(f_j ) = f_j (x_i)$ for all $i$ and $j.$" I don't get how the symbols $\hat x_1, \hat x_2,...,\hat x_n$ pop out of nowhere? How does the two theorems gurantee this comclusion? I am not quite getting it.

Comment: Basically there is a canonical isomorphism $\Psi: V \to V^{**}$ given by $\Psi v = (\varphi \mapsto \varphi(v))$. Take a basis for $V^*$, apply (2.24) to get a dual basis for $V^{**}$, and use $\Psi^{-1}$ to move that basis over to $V$. Use the definition of $\Psi$ to conclude that this basis is in fact dual to the original basis in $V^*$.

Comment: @Joppy What do you mean by a "canonical isomorphism" and by the symbol $\Psi v = (\varphi \mapsto \varphi(v))$ ?

Comment: $\Psi$ is a linear map $V \to V^{**}$, so for $v \in V$ the image $\Psi v$ is an element of $V^{**}$, i.e. it is some linear map $(\Psi v): V^* \to \mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the base field. For $\varphi \in V^*$, we define $\Psi v$ to be the function $\varphi \mapsto \varphi(v)$.

Comment: For the question you directly asked, $V^{**}$ is the dual space of $V^*$, and is not $V$. The basis $\{\hat x_1, \dots, \hat x_n\}$ they are talking about is defined from the basis $\{f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n\}$ of $V^*$ in exactly the same way that $\{f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n\}$ itself was defined from the basis $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ of $V$. The natural isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{**}$ does not come in until later, and it is shown that under this isomorphism it turns out that for each $i, x_i$ is mapped to $\hat x_i$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have added an answer to my post. Can you please check the answer, if it's correct or not?

Comment: @Joppy I have added an answer. Mind taking a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ which is an ordered basis for $V$, we may construct a dual basis for $V^{**}$ in the same way as we did in Theorem 2.24, i.e we consider the $ith$ coordinate function $g_i$ relative to the ordered basis $\beta'=\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ where $g_i(f)=a_i$, and $[f]_{\beta'}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\a_2\\.\\.\\.\\a_n\end{pmatrix},\forall f\in V^*.$ Thus, by Theorem 2.24, the set $\gamma=\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ so obtained is a dual basis of $\beta'.$ But, by Theorem 2.26,$\exists x_i\in V,$ ( where $i=1,2,...,n$) such that,$\psi(x_i)=\hat x_i=g_i.$ Since, $\psi$ is an isomorphism so, $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ and we can rewrite $\gamma$ as $\{\psi(x_1),\psi(x_2),...,\psi(x_n)\}=\{\hat x_1,\hat x_2,...,\hat x_n\}.$

Now, $g_i(f_j)=\delta_{ij}=\hat x_i(f_j)=f_j(x_i).$ So, $f_j(x_i)=\delta_{ij}.$ This means $f_j$ is the jth coordinate function with respect to the basis $\beta=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ (as if, $x\in V$ is an arbitrary vector then, $\exists b_1,b_2,...,b_n\in F $ such that $x=\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix_i$ and $[x]_{\beta}=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\.\\.\\.\\b_n\end{pmatrix}$ due to which, $f_j(x)=\sum_{i=1}^nb_if_j(x_i)=b_j.$)

From Theorem 2.24, we may conclude $\beta'$ is indeed a dual basis of $\beta.$ This completes the proof.

Comment: There are some problems with how you have written up your proof. These are not issues with the logic of the proof itself, but confusing things about how you have stated it. (1) there is no reason to introduce the symbols $g_i$ if you are just going to rename them to $\hat x_i$ a couple lines later. Just use $\hat x_i$ from the start. (2) "By theorem 2.26, there is an isomorphism $\psi : V\to V^{**}$. For each $i$, let $x_i = \psi^{-1}(\hat x_i)$" is much clearer than your startement that uses $\psi$ without introducing it, and lets readers follow the proof without reviewing Theorem 2.26 first.